# ChartJS displaying random datapoints out of order

Tags: chart.js

I'm using ChartJS 4 to build a simple time cartesian chart with two datasets, with each datapoint mapped to a point in time. ChartJS is picking up the data/date mapping just fine for the most part, however seeming at random, data points are displayed our of sequence.

[Screengrab of chart with datapoint out of place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojym1.png)

The data is supplied in date order so I have ruled out that data is being supplied out of sequence:

```
var graphDataDt = [{ x:'14-11-2023', y:'92'},{ x:'13-11-2023', y:'96'},{ x:'12-11-2023', y:'86'},{ x:'11-11-2023', y:'94'},{ x:'10-11-2023', y:'98'},{ x:'09-11-2023', y:'96'},{ x:'08-11-2023', y:'95'},{ x:'07-11-2023', y:'63'},{ x:'30-10-2023', y:'76'},{ x:'29-10-2023', y:'96'},{ x:'28-10-2023', y:'94'},{ x:'27-10-2023', y:'90'},{ x:'26-10-2023', y:'78'},{ x:'25-10-2023', y:'82'},{ x:'24-10-2023', y:'73'},{ x:'23-10-2023', y:'83'},{ x:'22-10-2023', y:'94'},{ x:'21-10-2023', y:'74'},{ x:'20-10-2023', y:'73'},{ x:'19-10-2023', y:'86'},{ x:'18-10-2023', y:'89'},{ x:'17-10-2023', y:'95'},{ x:'16-10-2023', y:'72'},{ x:'15-10-2023', y:'84'},{ x:'14-10-2023', y:'91'},{ x:'13-10-2023', y:'92'},{ x:'12-10-2023', y:'96'},{ x:'11-10-2023', y:'92'},{ x:'10-10-2023', y:'73'},{ x:'09-10-2023', y:'86'},{ x:'08-10-2023', y:'90'},{ x:'07-10-2023', y:'77'},{ x:'06-10-2023', y:'89'},{ x:'05-10-2023', y:'92'},{ x:'04-10-2023', y:'81'},{ x:'04-10-2023', y:'94'},{ x:'04-10-2023', y:'78'},{ x:'03-10-2023', y:'92'},{ x:'02-10-2023', y:'76'},{ x:'01-10-2023', y:'88'},{ x:'30-09-2023', y:'94'},{ x:'29-09-2023', y:'94'},{ x:'28-09-2023', y:'86'},{ x:'27-09-2023', y:'87'},{ x:'26-09-2023', y:'84'},{ x:'25-09-2023', y:'85'},{ x:'24-09-2023', y:'84'},{ x:'22-09-2023', y:'83'},{ x:'21-09-2023', y:'79'},{ x:'20-09-2023', y:'93'},];


var graphDataMt = [{ x:'14-11-2023', y:'79'},{ x:'13-11-2023', y:'63'},{ x:'12-11-2023', y:'83'},{ x:'11-11-2023', y:'81'},{ x:'09-11-2023', y:'81'},{ x:'08-11-2023', y:'78'},{ x:'07-11-2023', y:'73'},{ x:'30-10-2023', y:'81'},{ x:'29-10-2023', y:'90'},{ x:'28-10-2023', y:'83'},{ x:'27-10-2023', y:'84'},{ x:'26-10-2023', y:'65'},{ x:'25-10-2023', y:'74'},{ x:'24-10-2023', y:'77'},{ x:'23-10-2023', y:'68'},{ x:'22-10-2023', y:'85'},{ x:'21-10-2023', y:'83'},{ x:'20-10-2023', y:'63'},{ x:'19-10-2023', y:'67'},{ x:'18-10-2023', y:'76'},{ x:'17-10-2023', y:'73'},{ x:'16-10-2023', y:'70'},{ x:'15-10-2023', y:'70'},{ x:'14-10-2023', y:'83'},{ x:'13-10-2023', y:'66'},{ x:'12-10-2023', y:'80'},{ x:'11-10-2023', y:'67'},{ x:'10-10-2023', y:'80'},{ x:'09-10-2023', y:'73'},{ x:'08-10-2023', y:'80'},{ x:'07-10-2023', y:'78'},{ x:'06-10-2023', y:'68'},{ x:'05-10-2023', y:'72'},{ x:'04-10-2023', y:'73'},{ x:'04-10-2023', y:'57'},{ x:'04-10-2023', y:'57'},{ x:'03-10-2023', y:'65'},{ x:'02-10-2023', y:'69'},{ x:'01-10-2023', y:'77'},{ x:'30-09-2023', y:'70'},{ x:'29-09-2023', y:'68'},{ x:'28-09-2023', y:'76'},{ x:'27-09-2023', y:'74'},{ x:'26-09-2023', y:'76'},{ x:'25-09-2023', y:'68'},{ x:'24-09-2023', y:'69'},{ x:'23-09-2023', y:'84'},{ x:'22-09-2023', y:'66'},{ x:'21-09-2023', y:'82'},{ x:'20-09-2023', y:'84'},];
```

And here's the rest of my code

```
new Chart(speedBracketsMM, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {

      datasets: [{
        pointRadius: 0,
        label: 'Mobile',
        data: graphDataMt,
        backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor:'#990000',
        tension: 0.1
        },
        {
        pointRadius: 0,
        label: 'Desktop',
        data: graphDataDt,
        backgroundColor: '#FFBF00',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor:'#8f6b00',
        tension: 0.1
        }
        ]
    },
    options: {
    plugins: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Performance Scores',
            font: {
                        size: 16
                    }
            },
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom',
            labels:{
            usePointStyle: true,
            pointStyle: 'cirlce',
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
          },
      y: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Pages'
        }
      }
    }
  },
    
  });
```

I just can't figure it out. In this instance it's a single data point, in other instances it's 3 or 4, but in all cases, the data is supplied in data order.

Any thoughts would be massively appreciated.

I have tried stripping my code down to a basic ChartJS example, setting various date scale options and using basic data.

**EDIT/SOLUTION**
It seems the moment date library/adapter wasn't happy (unsure why). I've updated this to use the fns adapter, changed my date values to UNIX time stamps and all seems to be happy now without any additional x axis variables.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting x-axis to specifically parse 'time' in the format you supply.
For example:

```js
scales: {
  x: {
    type: 'time',
    time: {
      parser: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
      tooltipFormat: 'll'
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Date'
    },
    ticks: {
      source: 'auto'
    }
  },
  y: {
    // ... your existing y-axis configuration
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @PyariBilli, your answer didn't solve my issue but helped me on my way. Tried to add kudos, but not allowed and have added solution above.